Azure Terraform Create a Firewall rule for a flexible MySql Database
I have created 2 resources on Azure using Terraform:
1- A flexible MySql Database
resource "azurerm_mysql_flexible_server" "mysql" {
  name                   = var.db-name
  resource_group_name    = azurerm_resource_group.rg.name
  location               = azurerm_resource_group.rg.location
  administrator_login    = var.db-root-username
  administrator_password = var.db-root-password
  sku_name               = var.db-sku
  version                = "8.0.21"
  
  storage {
    size_gb = var.db-storage
  }
}

2- A Backend .Net Core Web-app Server
# Define BE Server Plan
resource "azurerm_service_plan" "apiplan" {
  name                = var.be-plan-name
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.rg.name
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.rg.location
  os_type             = var.be-plan-os-type
  sku_name            = var.be-plan-sku
}

# Create BE Server
resource "azurerm_linux_web_app" "be" {
  name                = var.be-server-name
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.rg.name
  location            = azurerm_service_plan.apiplan.location
  service_plan_id     = azurerm_service_plan.apiplan.id
  
  connection_string {
    name  = "Default"
    type  = "MySql"
    value = "Data Source=${azurerm_mysql_flexible_server.mysql.fqdn};Port=3306;Database=${var.db-schema-name};User Id=${var.db-root-username};Password=${var.db-root-password};Connect Timeout=300;"
  }

  site_config {   
    application_stack {
     dotnet_version  = "8.0"
    } 
  }
}

Now, what I need is to create a "azurerm_mysql_flexible_server_firewall_rule" in order to only allow access to the Database from the Backend Server.
How?

You can achieve this by using the azurerm_linux_web_app's outbound IP addresses within your azurerm_mysql_flexible_server_firewall_rule @NourMawla

can you give me implementation @VinayB because I tried it and I get the error The "for_each" map includes keys derived from resource attributes that cannot be determined until apply, and so Terraform cannot determine the full set of
│ keys that will identify the instances of this resource.


Create a Firewall rule for a flexible MySql Database using terraform.

Since you need only allows access from your Backend .NET Core Web App Server you can use the azurerm_mysql_flexible_server_firewall_rule resource in your Terraform configuration.
I tried a demo configuration which works as per the requriement
Configuration:
resource "azurerm_mysql_flexible_server" "mysql" {
  name                   = "vk-flexible-db"
  resource_group_name    = azurerm_resource_group.rg.name
  location               = azurerm_resource_group.rg.location
  administrator_login    = "myadmin"
  administrator_password = "INtel@199049"
  sku_name               = "GP_Standard_D2ds_v4"
  version                = "8.0.21"

  storage {
    size_gb = 20
  }
}


resource "azurerm_service_plan" "apiplan" {
  name                = "vk-e-plan"
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.rg.name
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.rg.location
  os_type             = "Linux"
  sku_name            = "B1"
}

resource "azurerm_linux_web_app" "be" {
  name                = "vk-e-server"
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.rg.name
  location            = azurerm_service_plan.apiplan.location
  service_plan_id     = azurerm_service_plan.apiplan.id

  connection_string {
    name  = "Default"
    type  = "MySql"
    value = "Data Source=${azurerm_mysql_flexible_server.mysql.fqdn};Port=3306;Database=mydb;User Id=myadmin;Password=YourStrongPassword!;Connect Timeout=300;"
  }

  site_config {
    application_stack {
      dotnet_version = "8.0"
    }
  }
}

locals {
  outbound_ips = length(azurerm_linux_web_app.be.outbound_ip_addresses) > 0 ? split(",", azurerm_linux_web_app.be.outbound_ip_addresses) : ["0.0.0.0"]
}

output "outbound_ip_addresses" {
  value = azurerm_linux_web_app.be.outbound_ip_addresses
}

resource "azurerm_mysql_flexible_server_firewall_rule" "allow_be_server" {
  name                = "allow-be-server"
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.rg.name
  server_name         = azurerm_mysql_flexible_server.mysql.name
  start_ip_address    = local.outbound_ips[0]
  end_ip_address      = local.outbound_ips[0]

  depends_on = [azurerm_linux_web_app.be]  
}

Deployment:



Refer:
azurerm_mysql_flexible_server | Resources | hashicorp/azurerm | Terraform | Terraform Registry
azurerm_mysql_flexible_server_firewall_rule | Resources | hashicorp/azurerm | Terraform | Terraform Registry
https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/values/locals

thank you so much @vinayB but I have a question please. Since I am only allowing 1 Ip address of the plenty outbound IP addresses available, will this cause a performance issue later? Do you recommend readding these Ips manually later on?

Glad to know it works for you @NourMawla coming to the question you asked Allowing only one IP address from the outbound IP addresses of your web app may limit connectivity and may end with performance issues if your app scales or requires multiple outbound IPs. It’s recommended to add more IP addresses manually or use a range to ensure better connectivity as your application grows.
